# How does the release of George Floyd's death footage change the perception of his death?

Tags: united-states, police, protests, racism, citizen-activism

The Daily Mail recently released the [bodycam footage of the death of George Floyd](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-8576371/Police-bodycam-footage-shows-moment-moment-arrest-George-Floyd-time.html). How does this video corroborate/counter the claims that have been made regarding the incident?

(One specific claim that has been made is that the police officers involved willfully murdered Floyd. Does the video provide strong evidence against this claim?)

Comment: I feel like this can be trivially answered by *watching the footage*.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a description of what the video shows, [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_of_George_Floyd):

> Derek Chauvin, a white police officer, knelt on Floyd's neck for almost eight minutes while Floyd was handcuffed and lying face down, begging for his life and repeatedly saying "I can't breathe". Officers J. Alexander Kueng and Thomas Lane further restrained Floyd, while officer Tou Thao prevented bystanders from intervening. During the final two minutes, Floyd was motionless and had no pulse while Chauvin ignored onlookers' pleas to remove his knee, which he did not do until medics told him to.

So **the video supports the claim that Floyd was willfully murdered by police**.

Comment: But he was saying he couldn't breath while standing and actively resisting arrest. You hear bystanders tell him that he should stop resisting. You hear officers reasoning with him. The man had meth, fentanyl, and more in his system + COVID and was not in his right mind. This wasn't murder. It was bad and they killed him, but it wasn't murder. Calling this murder sets the expectation that Ellison charged this correctly. I don't think he has. He has created a situation in which the police might be acquitted and walk, leading to more violence by people who don't understand WHY they will walk.

Comment: @acpilot To be clear, I did not say the video *proves* murder. We'll see what comes out in trial.

Comment: Your answer: "the video supports the claim that Floyd was willfully murdered by police."  But it doesn't. He died while being restrained by police.  That is not the same as murder.  Murder is premeditated and requires proof of an intent to kill.  It is not clear that the cops planned on killing him which is what has been charged.  The cops need to stand trial and answer for it, but throwing around the word "murder" is a serious thing.

Comment: @acpilot I bet most people have not even watched the whole video, or watched the version by CNN. That does not necessarily hinder them to have an opinion on the matter...

Comment: It's so much easier to just believe what you want than to actually understand what transpired.